# Custom AppBarButton from image

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-8, windows-8.1

Step by step, I'm optimizing my xaml to create a custom AppBarButton from an image. I've gone from a complete custom xaml layout to using a few lines using styles, but I know I can simplify this one more step.

Here's what I currently have:

```
<Style x:Key="PrintAppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="ButtonBase" BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="PrintAppBarButton"/>
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Print"/>
</Style>

<Button Style="{StaticResource PrintAppBarButtonStyle}">
    <ContentControl>
        <Image Source="/Assets/AppBar/appbar_printer_dark.png"/>
    </ContentControl>
</Button>
```

I know I can move the image source into the style definition, but I haven't been able to get this to work. After reading about the [AppBarButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbarbutton.aspx) class, I tried to set my *TargetType* to `AppBarButton` and then set an `Icon` property, but was unsuccessful. Something like the following:

```
<Style x:Key="PrintAppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="AppBarButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="PrintAppBarButton"/>
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Print"/>
    <Setter Property="Icon">
        <Setter.Value>
            // here it's expecting an IconElement
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Button Style="{StaticResource PrintAppBarButtonStyle}"/>
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

The `Icon` property does not accept an image -- if you need to use an image, stick with the `Content` property.  That can also be styled:

```
<Style x:Key="PrintAppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="ButtonBase" BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="PrintAppBarButton"/>
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Print"/>
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ContentControl>
                <Image Source="/Assets/AppBar/appbar_printer_dark.png"/>
            </ContentControl>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

---

By way of explanation, note that "ContentControl.Content" is the [`ContentProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.markup.contentpropertyattribute.aspx), which means that the child element gets set as "Content".  Ie, this:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource PrintAppBarButtonStyle}">
    <ContentControl>
        <Image Source="/Assets/AppBar/appbar_printer_dark.png"/>
    </ContentControl>
</Button>
```

is just shorthand for this:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource PrintAppBarButtonStyle}">
    <Button.Content>
        <ContentControl>
            <Image Source="/Assets/AppBar/appbar_printer_dark.png"/>
        </ContentControl>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Comment: I have tried this, but the image doesn't show up. I only get the empty circle.